# Running redis-server with stdin config

Tags: redis

I'm trying to run redis-server with - argument which basically takes basic redis conf file with stdin, but I can't get the server to start. I can't figure out what to do after I have set all the stuff I need. I even tried to browse the source if there's some magic keyword I need to type in the end but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Are you closing the stream on the writing side? I think a EOF is required.

Answer (score 4):

Press ctrl-D which will signal EOF.